# Selenium throws invalid argument exception when getting an element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to code a bot that automatically logins into a site.
This is the code for the login(I've only put the email for now)

```
    try:
        WebDriverWait(bot, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/input")))
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Loading took too much time!")

    mail = bot.find_element((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/input"))
```

When I go to get the element with find_element(), it gives me this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: expected value at line 1 column 11
```

I've looked up for some missing dependencies (like "from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By") but i got them all apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put redundant pair of parentheses there.
Instead of

```py
    mail = bot.find_element((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/input"))
```

It should be

```py
    mail = bot.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/input")
```

Also, you should improve your locators. Absolute XPaths are extremely fragile.

Comment: i've deleted the parentheses and now it works. one question, what can i use instead of absolute xpaths?

Comment: the relative XPath or other locators. You should learn how to create effective locators. Just google, you will find several tutorials for that